# Run-time error '424': Object required Excel VBA when using company website

Tags: excel, vba, automated-tests

Here i have given a dummy website, I'm using the below code to write something on the cell but i'm getting error "Run-time error '424': Object required".

I tried Facebook and it was working for me, Can this be resolved, I'm new to this VBA if someone can help me it will be very helpful.

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://company.com"
    
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    
    IE.document.getElementById("WD0367").Value = "A-1234"
End Sub
```

Tried using the above code and i was able to login to company website but information is not getting filled up and getting this error - Run-time error '424': Object required

Comment: Sounds like `getElementById("WD0367")` is not finding a match, though you've not told us which line gives the error.

Comment: May also want to do `DoEvents` in the loop. It should allow more background stuff to continue and also allows you to `Break` the Sub if needed.

Comment: Yes , it seems @TimWilliams is right, that element exist in the FB page but not in your dummy website. You need to find the element name in your dummy site. Open your dummy site in a browser and the open the developer tools for that browser. In Chrome press F12 to open and look in the elements tab.

Comment: @TimWilliams : I'm getting error on this line, can it be written in another syntax resolve the issue

 IE.document.getElementById("WD0367").Value = "A-1234"

Comment: It cannot be written in a different syntax if the element in question does not exist.

Comment: You've not posted the relevant HTML, so there's no way for us to see what you're working with.

Comment: Please see the HTML for the specific cell i copied.

<input name="WD0287" tabindex="0" title="" class="lsField__input" id="WD0287" type="text" size="40" maxlength="40" ct="CBS" ti="0" lsevents="{ActionItemActivate:[{ResponseData:'delta',ClientAction:'submit'},{}],Change:[{ResponseData:'delta',EnqueueCardinality:'single'},{}],DeleteItem:[{ResponseData:'delta'},{}],Select:[{ResponseData:'delta'},{}],Enter:[{ResponseData:'delta',ClientAction:'submit'},{}],ListAccess:[{ResponseData:'delta',ClientAction:'submitAsync'},{}],FieldHelpPress:

Comment: The id in the shown html part is `WD0287`. So you must use `IE.document.getElementById("WD0287").Value = "A-1234"` But I'm sure you will run in more trouble if you don't learn more about VBA, HTML and some more things. It can also be that the IE doesn't work anymore with the page you want to scrape.

Answer (score 0):

The code worked in excel2007 and windows10. Don't work in windows 11

```
'declare inside a module in Modules
Public ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer


'this function is in a sheet's module
Public Function example(Url As String) As String
   Dim objElement As Object
   
   example = vbNullString
   If ie Is Nothing Then
      Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
   End If
   If ie Is Nothing Then Exit Function
   
   ie.Navigate Url
   Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.ReadyState <> 4
      DoEvents
      'Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
   Loop
   If ie.LocationURL = Url Then           'instr(1,ie.LocationURL, Url) > 0 Then
      Set objElement = ie.Document.all("username")
      objElement.Value = Range("CC_USERNAME").Value2
      Set objElement = ie.Document.all("password")
      objElement.Value = SHEET_CODENAME.TextBox1.Value
      ie.Document.forms(0).submit
      Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.ReadyState <> 4
         DoEvents
      Loop
      '......YOUR CODE HERE 
      '......
      example = ie.LocationURL
   End If
   Set objElement = Nothing
End Function

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
   If Not (ie Is Nothing) Then
      ie.Quit
      Set ie = Nothing
   End If
End Sub
```